# Intel i5 12450H - Base Clock Frequency?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5, intel

I have a laptop with I5 - 12th gen - 12450h processor, on Intels website and google the base frequency mentioned for this is 3.3Ghz, but why does my laptop shows base frequency as 2.0 Ghz only?

Regards,

Please see attached pictures:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Because it can conserve battery power by increasing and decreasing the clock speed. Google Intel® Turbo Boost Technology. The clock rate ranges from 2 to 4.4 GHz on the performance cluster and 1.5 to 3.3 GHz on the efficient cluster.

Comment: [Your processor has the ability to adjust its frequency, 2.0 GHz appears to be caused by your power state.](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/132222/intel-core-i512450h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Intels website for your processor](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/sku/132222/intel-core-i512450h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz/specifications.html) does not list a "base" clock speed. It only lists turbo speeds for the performance and efficiency cores:

> | CPU Specifications |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | Total Cores | 8 |
> | # of Performance-cores | 4 |
> | # of Efficient-cores | 4 |
> | Total Threads | 12 |
> | Max Turbo Frequency | 4.40 GHz |
> | Performance-core Max Turbo Frequency | 4.40 GHz |
> | Efficient-core Max Turbo Frequency | 3.30 GHz |
> | Cache | 12 MB Intel® Smart Cache |
> | Processor Base Power | 45 W |
> | Maximum Turbo Power | 95 W |
> | Minimum Assured Power | 35 W |

There are no mentions of your processor "base" speed and it is likely determined by your laptop manufacturer based on the TDP that they specify based on the cooling system in the laptop. The only figures listed for "base" power is the processor TDP.

The only speeds listed are **peak** clock speeds available during processor boost/self-overclocking.